# How to print a random value name from a list?(python)

Tags: python, list

Let's say:

```
list=["A","B","C"]
listitem = random.randint(0,2)
```

I typed:

```
print listitem
```

but it gives a number and I'd like a letter?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the random index to reference the item in your list.

```
>>> import random
>>> list=["A","B","C"]
>>> listitem = random.randint(0,len(list))
>>> list[listitem]
'A'
>>> listitem = random.randint(0,len(list))
>>> list[listitem]
'B'
```

Or, if you don't care about the index, just select an item at random using the random.choice() routine:

```
>>> random.choice(list)
'B'
>>> random.choice(list)
'B'
>>> random.choice(list)
'A'
>>> random.choice(list)
'C'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random` :

```
 >>> from random import choice
 >>> List = [ 'A','B','C' ]
 >>> choice( List )
 C
 >>> choice( List )
 A
 >>> choice( List )
 B
```